# Laravel Sync not working base table not found

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database, laravel-7

I have this error

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 `Table 'skin_db.destination_destination_detail'` doesn't exist `(SQL: select * from `destination_destination_detail` where `destination_id` = 8)`
```

Where in fact I only have destinations and destination_details table. but the error is looking for `destination_destination_detail` table?

I really do not understand why.

Destination model

```php
public function details(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Destination_detail');
}
```

Controller

```php
$destination = Destination::find($req->destination_id);    
$destination->details()->sync($req->provinces);
```

Comment: if you only have 2 tables you do not have a `BelongsToMany` relationship; that requires a pivot ... Laravel convention assumes the pivot table name to be be Model A + Model B which would Destination + Destination Detail (`destination_destination_detail`), if you wanted to use a different table name for the pivot you would have to use the other arguments for `belongsToMany` to define that

Comment: nothing to do with your issue but underscores in a models name is taboo, capcase DestinationDetail

Comment: @lagbox, I get it now!.. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the relation many to many you must create another table it's name `destination_destination_detail` with columns:

```sql
destination_detail_id
destination_id
```

both of them are **foreign key**